# Sophisticated data structers in JVM

Tags: java, data-structures, jvm

I'm looking for a really specialized data strutures (stacks, queues, graphs, maps) that would siplify problems, I need that for my master thesis. I think that JVM must use such, in thier implementation of garbage collection, heaps of method, or stacks of object. Is there any good paper/book describing that?

Answer (score 1):

Java SE has [a stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), several [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html) implementations and several [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) implementations.  I do not recall a graph implementation in the std lib, however, a quick googling should give you some customized exmaples

Answer (score 0):

For stacks, queues, and maps, you can definitely look at the source code for the JDK itself. For example, [TreeMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java). The problem I see though is that they're not necessarily designed with ease of understanding in mind, as they're just meant to be practical and efficient.

The [Algorithm Design Manual](http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf) is pretty useful as well.